# Upgrade version of elasticsearch from 0.90.7 to 1.6.1

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am new in elasticsearch and I have by mistake installed 0.90.7 version in my server. Now I want to install shield for this I have to upgrade my elasticsearch version to 1.5 or above. So I need to Upgrade version without loosing existing data. Can anybody help me how to upgrade version to 1.6.1?

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade your Elasticsearch version from 0.90.x to 1.x in the following way

**[Cluster restart upgrade process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html#restart-upgrade)**

Before upgrading Elasticsearch, it is a good idea to consult the [**breaking changes**](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes.html) docs.

As per Elasticsearch Documentation before performing an upgrade, it’s a good idea to back up the data on your system.